# What is the reason that Piston needs to remove the OAuth keys from the request?

Tags: django, django-piston

I posted the question in here as well but dont seem get answered.. 
https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/issue/194/what-is-the-reason-that-piston-needs-to

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it's doing so for security purposes.

The `Resource` class handles authentication using the request object, then removes the OAuth headers from the request before the given handler is called. Generally, you'll want to limit the visibility of things like these. If you limit exposure of private information like keys, etc, you can potentially limit vulnerabilities.